# Transition between links using Tab - exclusion some links

Tags: html, css

I have page with main menu, some links in main content and left menu. The site must be adapted for the blind...

So, when I want to use tab buton to transition between links the order is:

1. Main menu
2. Content
3. Left menu

Is it possible to add some values to `<a>` tag to 'excluded' it?

Comment: `<a>` is a *tag*, not an *attribute*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to add correct `tabindex` values for doing something like this. So, if you have such a requirement and you don't have the same HTML structure, you can use `tabindex` to modify the control flow.

Consider this example:

```html
<input value="Last" tabindex="3" />
<input value="First" autofocus tabindex="1" />
<input value="Middle" tabindex="2" />
```

Now in the above fiddle, see how pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key affects the control. You can achieve similar if you can use `tabindex`.